# Stick SwiftUI List section to the top

Tags: list, swiftui

With below code the SwiftUIList Section does not stick to the top.

From the image, even If the section height is few points it shows space at the top and does not stick to the List at the top.

Any idea how can we stick this to the top or it consumes only the height needed for it and does not leave extra space at the top.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var data = createData()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(data, id: \.name) { header in
                    Section {
                        ForEach(header.items, id: \.self) { item in
                            Text(item)
                        }
                    } header: {
                        Text(header.name)
                            .background(Color.purple)
                    }
                }
            }
            .listStyle(.plain)
            .navigationTitle("Hello Users")
            .background(Color.cyan)
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}

struct UserDataSection {
    var name: String
    var items: [String]
}

func createData() -> [UserDataSection] {
    var sections: [UserDataSection] = []
    sections.append(UserDataSection(name: "Admin Users", items: createDataSet1()))
    sections.append(UserDataSection(name: "Generic Users", items: createDataSet2()))
    return sections
}


func createDataSet1() -> [String] {
    var items: [String] = []
    for i in 0..<20 {
        items.append("User \(i)")
    }
    return items
}

func createDataSet2() -> [String] {
    var items: [String] = []
    for i in 20..<40 {
        items.append("User \(i)")
    }
    return items
}
```

[image]

Comment: You need a LazyVStack with a “pinned view” from a Section

Comment: Problem with LazyVStack is if the list grows the memory consumption also will increase. Does it offer reusability of rows like List?